# Class Cast exception error: trying to write the into the file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to export the file but an getting the following exception:

> An unexpected error occurred: java.lang.Exception:
>   sailpoint.tools.GeneralException: The application script threw an
>   exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList to java.lang.String BSF info:
>   Export File - Abc at line: 0 column: columnNo

My code is below:

```
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.*;

    String appname = "Abc";
    String path = "//home/exportfile//";
    String filename = path+"ApplicationExport-"+appname+".txt";
    String ret = "false";

    QueryOptions ops = new QueryOptions();
    Filter [] filters = new Filter[1];
    filters[0] = Filter.eq("application.name", appname);
    ops.add(filters);

    List props = new ArrayList();
    props.add("identity.name");

    //Do search
    Iterator it = context.search(Link.class, ops, props);

    //Build file and export header row
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
    out.write("IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization");
    out.newLine();          

    //Iterate Search Results
    if (it!=null)
    {                               
            while ( it.hasNext() ) {
                    //Get link and create object
                    Object [] record = it.next();
                    String identityName = (String) record[0];
                    Identity user = (Identity) context.getObject(Identity.class, identityName);

                    //Get Identity attributes for export
                    String workforceid = (String) user.getAttribute("workforceID");                 

                    //Get application attributes for export
                    String userid="";
                      String org="";
                    List links = user.getLinks();
                    if (links!=null)
                    {
                            Iterator lit = links.iterator();
                            while (lit.hasNext())
                            {
                                    Link l = lit.next();
                                    String lname = l.getApplicationName();
                                    if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname))
                                    {
                                              userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
                                              org= (String) l.getAttribute("Organization");
                                    }
                            }
                    }                               

                    //Output file
                    out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+org);                             
                    out.newLine();                                                                          
                    out.flush();
            }                       
            ret="true";
    }
    //Close file and return
    out.close();
    return ret;
```

While running the above code i am getting the cast exception error: since the Organization attribute is Multivalued.i.e.: in that attribute you can have more than one value.

any help to correct this code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it clearly, you are getting an object of type `sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList` and trying to cast it to a string.

From your question i understand the problem is here:

```
org= (String) l.getAttribute("Organization");
```

So you need to change it to:

```
sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList orgList = (sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList) l.getAttribute("Organization");
```

and then extract the correct value from that list.

Comment: Changing the above values didnt help..
do you recommend using List or ArrayList for that attribute? I am very new to Java.so no clue where to change this code?

Comment: The code ran without error.but it didnt write anything in Organization column.

Comment: so that means it **did** work. now you have a different problem. you can update the question with the new code and describe the new problem.

Comment: Do you recommend anything why it the code didnt wrote anything in File?

Comment: update the question with the new code and explain exactly what is the new problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742453/code-is-not-writing-the-values-in-file
you can find the post here