# Code is not writing the values in File

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to export the file.

my Code is below:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.*;


String appname = "Abc";
String path = "//home/exportfile//";
String filename = path+"ApplicationExport-"+appname+".txt";
String ret = "false";

QueryOptions ops = new QueryOptions();
Filter [] filters = new Filter[1];
filters[0] = Filter.eq("application.name", appname);
ops.add(filters);

List props = new ArrayList();
props.add("identity.name");

//Do search
Iterator it = context.search(Link.class, ops, props);

//Build file and export header row
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
out.write("IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization");
out.newLine();          

//Iterate Search Results
if (it!=null)
{                               
        while ( it.hasNext() ) {
                //Get link and create object
                Object [] record = it.next();
                String identityName = (String) record[0];
                Identity user = (Identity) context.getObject(Identity.class, identityName);

                //Get Identity attributes for export
                String workforceid = (String) user.getAttribute("workforceID");                 

                //Get application attributes for export
                String userid="";
                  String org="";
                List links = user.getLinks();
                if (links!=null)
                {
                        Iterator lit = links.iterator();
                        while (lit.hasNext())
                        {
                                Link l = lit.next();
                                String lname = l.getApplicationName();
                                if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname))
                                {
                                          userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
                                         sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList orgList = (sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList) l.getAttribute("Organization");

                                }
                        }
                }                               

                //Output file
                out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+org);                             
                out.newLine();                                                                          
                out.flush();
        }                       
        ret="true";
}
//Close file and return
out.close();
return ret;
```

Code is writing the value for 3 columns except Organization column. Not sure why?

Can you pls help me to identify what is wrong with the code. Or what i am missing.

By the way, Organization column is multivalue i.e. that column might have more than one value.

so the final output should be,

```
IdentityName,  UserName,  WorkforceID,  Organization 
1,             abc,       123,          internal
1,             abc,       123,          external
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can see you're never assigning a value other than `""` to `org`...

Answer (score 1):

String org=""; is empty. It seems no where you assigned value to org, so empty value is being written to file.

Comment: even if i comment out that value it writes the empty value only.

Comment: You need to assign value to org, not comment out. For example, change   String org=""; to String org="myOrganization" and see, you will get myOrganization in output.

Comment: but that would be hardcoded value.how do i get the dynamic value for that organization column?
the way i am getting for the remainig 3 columns?

Comment: I guess. from orgList you need to get organization and assign it org. Because it is specific to your application, I can't answer confidently.

Answer (score 0):

you defined `org=""` so it'll write an empty string.

You get an organization list:

```
sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList orgList = (sailpoint.tools.xml.PersistentArrayList) l.getAttribute("Organization");
```

this object probably have methods for getting the values you need, so you can do something like:

```
org = orgList.getOrganization();
```

Of course this is just an example, since i don't know the exact structure of the object, using an IDE you can explore the different methods this object has and find out what you need.

Comment: i got the below error while running the code:

An unexpected error occurred: java.lang.Exception: sailpoint.tools.GeneralException: BeanShell script error: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.FileWriter; import java.io.File; import java.io.B . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getOrganization() on undefined variable or class name: orgList : at Line: 53 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.FileWriter; import java.io.File; import java.io.B . . . '' : orgList .getOrganization ( ) BSF info

Comment: did you read the entire answer? this is just an example, i have no idea if your object has a `getOrganization()` method (it probably doesn't), use Eclipse, it will help you greatly: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junor